# regex dealing with brackets

Tags: python, regex, regexp-replace

I have multiple strings like

```
string1 = """[[拱|{{{#!html}}}]][br]팔짱낄 공''':'''"""
string2 = """[[顆|{{{#!html}}}]][br]낟알 과'''-'''[* some annotation that may include quote marks(', ") and brackets("(", ")", "[[", "]]").]""" 
string3 = """[[廓|{{{#!html}}}]][br]둘레 곽[br]클 확[* another annotation.][* another annotation.]"""
strings = [string1, string2, string3]
```

Every string does contain one or more "[br]"s.

Each string may or may not include annotations.

Every annotation starts with "[*" and ends with "]". It may include double brackets("[[" and "]]"), but never  single ones("[" and "]"), so there won't be any confusion (e.g. [* some annotation with [[brackets]]]).

The words I want to replace are the words between the first "[br]" and the annotation(if any exists, otherwise, the end of the string), which are

```
word1 = """팔짱낄 공''':'''"""
word2 = """낟알 과'''-'''"""
word3 = """둘레 곽[br]클 확"""
```

So I tried

```
for string in strings:
    print(re.sub(r"\[br\](.)+?(\[\*)+", "AAAA", string))
```

expecting something like

```
[[拱|{{{#!html}}}]][br]AAAA
[[顆|{{{#!html}}}]][br]AAAA[* some annotation that may include quote marks(', ") and brackets("(", ")", "[[", "]]").]
[[廓|{{{#!html}}}]][br]AAAA[* another annotation.][* another annotation.]
```

The logic for the regex was

`\[br\]` : the first "[br]"

`(.)+?` : one or more characters that I want to replace, lazy

`(\[\*)+` : one or more "[*"s

But the result was

```
[[拱|{{{#!html}}}]][br]팔짱낄 공''':'''
[[顆|{{{#!html}}}]]AAAA some annotation that may include quote marks(', ") and brackets("(", ")", "[[", "]]").]
[[廓|{{{#!html}}}]]AAAA another annotation.][* another annotation.]
```

instead. I also tried `r"\[br\](.)+?(\[\*)*"` but still not working. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use

```
^(.*?\[br]).+?(?=\[\*.*?](?<!].)(?!])|$)
```

The pattern matches

- `^` Start of string
- `(.*?\[br])` Capture **group 1**, match as least as possible chars until the first occurrence of `[br]`
- `.+?` Match any char 1+ times
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert at the right

  - `\[\*.*?](?<!].)(?!])` Match `[*` till `]` not surrounded by `]`
  - `|` Or
  - `$` Assert end of string
- `)` Close lookahead

Replace with capture group 1 and `AAAA` like `\1AAAA`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fBjKWp/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/wO9MOm)

Example code

```
import re

pattern = r"^(.*?\[br]).+?(?=\[\*.*?](?<!].)(?!])|$)"

s = ("[[拱|{{{#!html}}}]][br]팔짱낄 공''':'''\n"
            "[[顆|{{{#!html}}}]][br]낟알 과'''-'''[* some annotation that may include quote marks(', \") and brackets(\"(\", \")\", \"[[\", \"]]\").]\n"
            "[[廓|{{{#!html}}}]][br]둘레 곽[br]클 확[* another annotation.][* another annotation.]")

subst = "$1AAAA"
result = re.sub(pattern, r"\1AAAA", s, 0, re.MULTILINE)
print(result)
```

Output

```
[[拱|{{{#!html}}}]][br]AAAA
[[顆|{{{#!html}}}]][br]AAAA[* some annotation that may include quote marks(', ") and brackets("(", ")", "[[", "]]").]
[[廓|{{{#!html}}}]][br]AAAA[* another annotation.][* another annotation.]
```

Answer (score 1):

The best I could come up with is first checking if there are any annotations:

```
import re
r = re.compile(r'''
    (\[br])      
    (.*?)
    (\[\*.*\]$)
''', re.VERBOSE)

annotation = re.compile(r'''
    (\[\*.*]$)
''', re.VERBOSE)

def replace(m):
    return m.group(1) + "AAAA" + m.group(3)

for s in string1, string2, string3:
    print()
    print(s)
    if annotation.search(s):
        print(r.sub(replace, s))
    else:
        print(re.sub(r'\[br](.*)', '[br]AAAA', s))
```

which gives the expected output:

```
[[拱|{{{#!html}}}]][br]팔짱낄 공''':'''
[[拱|{{{#!html}}}]][br]AAAA

[[顆|{{{#!html}}}]][br]낟알 과'''-'''[* some annotation that may include quote marks(', ") and brackets("(", ")", "[[", "]]").]
[[顆|{{{#!html}}}]][br]AAAA[* some annotation that may include quote marks(', ") and brackets("(", ")", "[[", "]]").]

[[廓|{{{#!html}}}]][br]둘레 곽[br]클 확[* another annotation.][* another annotation.]
[[廓|{{{#!html}}}]][br]AAAA[* another annotation.][* another annotation.]
```

I suppose you could move the if into the replace function, but I'm not sure if that would be much of an improvement. It would look something like:

```
import re
r = re.compile(r'''
    ^(?P<prefix>.*)
    (?P<br>\[br].*?)
    (?P<annotation>\[\*.*\])?
    (?P<rest>[^\[]*)$
''', re.VERBOSE)

def replace(m):
    g = m.groupdict()
    if g['annotation'] is None:
        return g['prefix'] + "[br]AAAA" + g['rest']
    # the prefix will contain all but the last [br], thus the split...
    return g['prefix'].split('[br]')[0] + "[br]AAAA" + g['annotation'] + g['rest']

for s in string1, string2, string3:
    print()
    print(s)
    print(r.sub(replace, s))
```

Comment: Can I add an additional argument `n`, related to the index of the string, to `replace(m)`?
In fact, the new words are not identical: I would have ["AAAA", "BBBB", "CCCC"] instead of ["AAAA", "AAAA", "AAAA"].